# Play audio with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, audio

I'm currently using [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and command-line `mplayer` to play audio on the local machine, with my Node.JS application. This works, but it's not really an excellent solution. My biggest issue is that it takes 500ms from mplayer is started to audio starts playing.

Are there better ways to play audio? Preferably compressed audio, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: @lanzz Yeah I though I had, might need to recheck that

Comment: What is the application for this?  Do you need really low-latency audio over the internet?

Comment: Hey @Znarkus did you find anything? Also in the same boat, most existing modules use child process...which means latency, or they don't support stopping/pausing audio. I'm trying to commit blasphemy by making a midi sound board in nodejs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you asking is there any good modules that work with audio in the nodejs ecosystem?

Whenever you have this type of question you should first go the [npmjs](https://npmjs.org/) and just type a appropiate keyword.

Here is list of modules that related to [audio](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/audio) I found on the npmjs site.

substacks's [baudio](https://github.com/substack/baudio) looks good to me.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough that I wanted to play audio *files*. Sorry about that. Thanks for the link, *komponist* / *mpd* was actually something I could use. But I'm going to keep it simple for this project, and try my luck with `mplayer -slave`.

Comment: baudio is definitely *not* what you want for playing audio files

Answer (score 41):

I would suggest using [node-speaker](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker), which outputs raw PCM data to your speakers (so basically, it plays audio).

If you're playing something like mp3 files you might need to decode it first to PCM data, which is exactly what [node-lame](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame) does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you find anything that does not require python?

Answer (score 19):

Introducing, [`audic`](https://github.com/Richienb/audic). It doesn't use any native dependencies so it can't break like in the answers higher up.

Observe:

```js
import Audic from 'audic';

const audic = new Audic('audio.mp3');

await audic.play();

audic.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    audic.destroy();
});
```

or more simply:

```js
import {playAudioFile} from 'audic';

await playAudioFile('audio.mp3');
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked cross-platform for me. Downside: no callback for when audio is finished playing (as far as I can tell). Upside: works with high quality .m4a and lets me load everything before playing it.

Comment: @JeffHykin Since Audic allows pausing, using a callback for when it completes doesn't work here. However, like the Web Audio API, you can use `audio.duration` in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: That is helpful to know. A promise that resolves on pause or end-of-sound (whichever comes first) would be very handy. A promise that resolves on sound-end (and never resolves if paused) would also be handy though. The setTimeout seems a little bit hacky.

Comment: does it really work in linux?As far as I have tried it does not work in ubunutu 18.04 lts.

Comment: @liaguridio Audic depends on VLC to work. It is only automatically downloaded for Windows and macOS because there are many Linux distributions.

Comment: Would love some additional documentation for this

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi https://www.richie-bendall.ml/audic/classes/audic.html

Comment: @RichieBendall, happy 3000 :)

Comment: @Aerodynamika VLC supports lots of audio formats and is already installed on lots of devices. What's the main problem with using it here?

Answer (score 13):

Simplest I've found (on Mac OS) is to use

```
exec('afplay whatever.mp3', audioEndCallback)
```

Comment: There's also [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/open.1.html) command on OS X.

Comment: Don't forget `const { exec } = require('child_process');`

Answer (score 9):

Check out [sound-play](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sound-play), it's a simple solution that works on Windows and MacOS without using external players:

```
const sound = require('sound-play')
sound.play('music.mp3')
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package.

Comment: can you share the document about sound-play? How to pause/play, increase/decrease volume or stop playing?

Comment: This calls `afplay` on macOS and Windows Media Player on Windows, which are external players

Comment: Yeah, is there a way how it can work without running afplay?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [node-groove](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-groove) - Node.js binding to libgroove:

> This library provides decoding and encoding of audio on a playlist. It is intended to be used as a backend for music player applications, however it is generic enough to be used as a backend for any audio processing utility.

Disclaimer: I wrote the library, which is free, open source, and not affiliated with any product, service, or company.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I really like libgroove.  However, you might want to mention that you wrote it.

Comment: why is that relevant? the answer's quality is unaffected by the author of the module.

Comment: I believe @BonsaiOak is correct. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) says: "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: @TachyonVortex fair enough. Updated.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `play-sound` module also:

Install using npm, Run command:

```
npm install play-sound --save
```

Now use in your code:

```
var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {})

 player.play('./music/somebody20.flac', function (err) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Audio finished");
 });
```

Comment: That module just executes a command (eg mplayer), like the OP is already doing

Comment: @zoran404 And if mplayer isn't pre-installed, It would fall back to other players that don't have native support for other audio formats i.e. mp3. I was wondering if there was a more platform-agnostic library that has support for at least prevalent formats.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the play sound module and path to achieve this.

```
npm install play-sound

import path from 'path'; 
const __dirname = path.resolve();
import sound from 'sound-play';

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "file.mp3");
sound.play(filePath);
```

Comment: can you share the document about play-sound? How to pause/play, increase/decrease volume or stop playing?

Comment: @trungkmy here is the link to the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as sound from 'sound-play';

sound.play(path.join(path.resolve(), "notify.mp3"));
```