# How do I play sound in my node.js chatroom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have been looking up how to play sound with node.js all day, I can't use "document.getElementById" and I can't use "new Audio" either. I want it to be able to play sound when I do @everyone in my chatroom. The audio file is name "ping.mp3" and is in the same path as my main node.js file. I need some recommendations or code snippets. Thanks!

---

**This is a code snippet of where the ping code is.**

```
  function highlight(message){
    if(message == "") {
        return message
    }
    let mentions = message.match(/@\b([A-Za-z0-9]+)\b/g)
    let urlCheck1 = message.split(` `)
    
    if (mentions === null ) { return message }
    for (i = 0; i < mentions.length; i++) {
      let urlCheck = urlCheck1[i].includes(`http`)
        let mention = mentions[i].substring(1)
        if(sesskx.has(mention) && !urlCheck) {
            message = message.replace(mentions[i], `<span class="name-color">@${mention}</span>`)
        } else if (mention == 'everyone') {
            ping.play();
            message = message.replace(mentions[i], `<span class="name-color">@${mention}</span>`)
        } else if (mention == 'here') {
            ping.play();
            message = message.replace(mentions[i], `<span class="name-color">@${mention}</span>`)
        }
        else {
          return message;
        }
    }
    return message
 };
```

I want "ping.play();" to make the sound.

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543237/play-audio-with-node-js

Comment: I tried but none of them work for [my project](https://froggy-chatroom.unluckyfroggy.repl.co/).

Comment: Could you post some of your nodejs script here so we can see what you are doing?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible but kind of tricky. You can use [`play-sound`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound) to take care of it for you:

```js
var player = require('play-sound')(opts = {})
 
player.play('foo.mp3', function(err){
  if (err) throw err
});
```

What it basically does is look for sound players in the environment and try to use one of them to play the mp3:

```js
const { spawn, execSync } = require('child_process');
// List of players used
const players = [
    'mplayer',
    'afplay',
    'mpg123',
    'mpg321',
    'play',
    'omxplayer',
    'aplay',
    'cmdmp3'
];
// find a player by seeing what command doesn't error
let player;
for(const p of players) {
  if (isExec(p)) {
    player = p;
    break;
  }
}

function isExec(command) {
  try{
    execSync(command)
    return true
  }
  catch {
    return false
  }
}
spawn(player, ['ping.mp3']);
```

Comment: It says that all of the players cannot be found.

Comment: Then install a player?

Answer (score -2):

If you are creating a node.js server, node.js is back-end/server side, so users won't be able to hear anything that happens if a sound is "played" there. So you'll have to do it client side using "new Audio()", when the client receives a message including "@everyone" (which I don't understand why you cant use, you can send the mp3 file [to the client with the page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509666/sending-whole-folder-content-to-client-with-express)).
I also made an example for you on [repl](https://repl.it/@gearDev/Stack-overflow#Public/client.js).

Comment: Easter egg for some day when someone hooks up speakers to that server and hear 1000's of pings over and over 

Comment: Haha, yes @Trevor

Comment: my problem is that the pinging function is in index.js so I have to add to index.js

Comment: new Audio is not allowed when using node.js

Comment: That's literally how I made the first 20 lines of my project.