# How to play audio directly through node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, audio

I want to play audio without having to use HTML and just do it with node. The program is a webscraper that I want to alert me with a sound when needed. I looked up online for packages but I couldn't find any that worked. If there is any way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Can you share some examples of which libraries you tried and where you got stuck? I skimmed npmjs.com quickly and found half a dozen that look straightforward and up to date.

Comment: Yah, play-sound, play, baudio.

Comment: @Marty can you post any that I didn't mention.

Comment: As you mentioned in your question "You didn't find any" - Are you looking for some specific lib or tool to help you out? As Marty mentioned, you can simply google search it and there are  enough of them. For playing an alert sound, you can check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/play-sound) out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12543237/8876321

Comment: is your node server running locally like on your laptop ( so node has access to your sound driver ) or are you asking to have the audio get rendered from some web page where the node is a remote server ?  ... this distinction makes a world of difference

Comment: @ScottStensland locally